# Replace scene after loading done

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone, scene

I'm new to cocos2d and Objective C, making some first steps, and have problem that I can't beat. I have 2 scenes, 1st loading some files, than after loading I want to switch to main scene, but can't do that at all. I've maked progress bar of loading elements, and I want to fo to the next scene after loading complete. But it doesn't replace scene and just exit application. Here's part code of PreloaderScene:

```
    +(id) scene
{
    CCScene *scene = [CCScene node];
    CCLayer* layer = [PreloaderScene node];
    [scene addChild:layer];
    return scene;
}

- (id) init
{
        if ((self = [super init]))
        {


            int n=5;

            CCLabelTTF *label = [CCLabelTTF labelWithString:@"Loading..." fontName:@"Marker Felt" fontSize:64];
            CGSize size = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] winSize];
            label.position =  ccp( size.width /2 , size.height/2 );
            [self addChild: label];

            CCSprite *Bar = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"200x30.png"];
            Bar.position = ccp(size.width /2 , size.height/2-70);
            [self addChild:Bar];
            CCSprite *Progress = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"2x30.png"];
            Progress.position = ccp (size.width/2-100+1, size.height/2-70);
            [self addChild:Progress];

            ResourceManager *Resource = [[ResourceManager alloc] init];
            for (int i=1;i<=n;i++)
            {
                NSString *imageName =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"image%d.png",i];
                [Resource LoadImage:imageName];

                [Progress runAction:[CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:1 position:ccp (size.width/2-100+i/n*100, size.height/2-70)]];
                [Progress runAction:[CCScaleBy actionWithDuration:1 scaleX:i/n*100 scaleY:1]];
            }
            [[CCDirector sharedDirector] replaceScene:MainScene];   
        }
        return self;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont see where you are creating the MainScene to be able to use it for the replacement. Could that be the issue?
Maybe you need to create it like the following

```
 MainScene *scene = [MainScene node];
[[CCDirector sharedDirector] replaceScene:scene];
```

You need to actually create the mainscene before you can use it.

Answer (score 0):

am also new to Cocos2D but as my knowledge i found answers for you

1. one reason is your not creating `Main Scene` before you're using it
2. you can't call `replaceScene` with in the init method of a another Scene.That will cause 
   CCDirector to crash....